# Can I use PUT with an HttpUrlConnection to send a image to my shared host account?

Tags: java, file, upload, httpurlconnection

A little in disbelief Java makes it this easy on the client side. I was convinced I was going to have to post an image over to a server file to sanitize it first, but I also want to keep anyone from accessing a server file like that (and thinks a little) and ends up spamming me with pics. I need the process strict with no potential tampering by the end user.

From what I read if I understand it right, a PUT should be just what I need. A signed ja of mine sends a site related informational image from client to server without exposing any of my FTP info or revealing a upload file that can be attacked. Do I have the right grasp of PUT is my question I guess. It will place an image on my account over http without an extra handling process?

How could I use this snippet for an image by the way?

```
URLConnection urlconnection=null;
try{
File file = new File("C:/test.txt");
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.5.27/Test/test.txt");
urlconnection = url.openConnection();
urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlconnection.setDoInput(true);

if (urlconnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
try {
((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).setRequestMethod("PUT");
((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/html");
((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).connect();


} catch (ProtocolException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}


BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlconnection
 .getOutputStream());
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
 file));
int i;
// read byte by byte until end of stream
while ((i = bis.read()) >0) {
 bos.write(i);
}
System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getResponseMessage());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
try {

InputStream inputStream;
int responseCode=((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getResponseCode();
if ((responseCode>= 200) &&(responseCode<=202) ) {
inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getInputStream();
int j;
while ((j = inputStream.read()) >0) {
 System.out.println(j);
}

} else {
inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getErrorStream();
}
((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).disconnect();

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The vast majority of web servers do not implement the PUT command like you're imagining. The PUT command is generally not useful outside of the WebDAV protocol or custom REST APIs.